Deserialize JSON to already filled class in C#
I have to make multiple requests to get some data from a REST webAPI (it's a lot of data and the service doesn't give it to me all in one single request).
To do that, I'm using do while and it's all working fine.
My question is simple: is there a way of, when I deserialize the result, add the additional data to the previous data?
I'm using:
Data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyCLASS>(Content);

and I'm looking for something like:
Data += JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyCLASS>(Content);  //syntax error

I know a workaround to this. But it implies to declare another MyClass (to fill with all the data), create a list, add the new data, convert the list to an array and overwrite MyClass at every request. Something like the '+=' operator woulb be great (or another easier method). Do you know how?

You need to implement the += operator of MyCLASS

How do I do that? I didn't know that's possible!

You overload the + operator, the += is implicitly overloaded.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/operator-overloading

You can't avoid having to manually write code to add any data of one MyCLASS instance to another , but if you will be more specific we can try to help you to minimize it.

I'm goint to try to implement the operator.

Alternative, you should look for List<T>.Add(T) Method

The .NET framework guidelines do not recommend to overload the plus operator for such operations. see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/operator-overloads I would recommend to just use a method.

Just a quick note: Only implement the operator if it actually makes sense to add two instances of your class this way. Otherwise you might end up looking at this code 6 months from now and wonder how the hell this works and why

Also, only overload + if it makes sense to also overload - (even though it's not as strict  as == and != where you can't overload just one of them)

Thank you for the tip. I think I got it.

To confirm, you are using Json.NET, correct?  If so, this looks to be a duplicate of Populate an existing object with JSON, agree?

What kind of data are you receiving? It seem strange to send only part of a single object in a response. I would have expected some natural way to split objects, like only returning 100 objects for each call, with some info on how to fetch the next batch, or to handle large binary data in some special way.
